# add value to enum java

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have an enum in class file which is in jar file.

```
public static enum test{
    Test, Test1;
}
```

Now I want to add an new value to this enum.So How can add new value from my custom class?

Comment: You cannot do that. Review [what enums are](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Enums are complete static enumeration.